# Creating a Class with variable properties

Tags: python-2.7

Hi I am interested in creating a class somewhat like this

**- Class Tutor**

- Tutor First Name
- Tutor Last Name
- Tutor age
- Tutor primary subjects
- Tutor secondary subjects

My main issues is with the subjects, a tutor may have 1 to 10 primary subjects and similarly 1 to 10 secondary subjects, not all tutors will have have the same number of primary and secondary subjects so the class I am trying to create needs to be flexible enough to accommodate any number of primary & secondary subject combinations.
How best to create a data structure that I can use like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [List](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#), or [tuple](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html) if you want several data types in the list.

```
class Tutor:
    firstName = ""
    lastName = ""
    age = 0
    primarySubjects = []
    secondarySubjects = []
```